# Why does C++20 not allow a concept declared nested in a class?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, standards, c++20, c++-concepts

```
struct A
{
    template<typename T>
    concept IsGood = sizeof(T) == sizeof(int); 
    // error: concept declarations may only appear in global or namespace scope

    void f(IsGood auto n)
    {}
};

int main()
{
    A{}.f(8);
}
```

See online demo: https://godbolt.org/z/fv5fePdbf

Now that we can define a class nested in another class, then,

**Why does C++20 not allow a concept declared nested in a class?**

Comment: Similar to `using` declaration, you can have `concept`  which may depend upon the template parameter..